# NSArrayController does not update content for second window

Tags: objective-c, macos, window

I'm writing an OSX app where a second window is opened to show results when the button on the first window is pushed. The window-2 start fine and shows what I want. But when I change inputs in window-1 and hit the action button again the window-2 doesn't update the results.

here my questions:

1. how does the content of window-2 update after input change in window-1
2. how is window-2 closed and released (right now window-2 shows up with the same content before closed when action button is pushed again)

here is the code for the action button:

```
- (IBAction)pushRun:(id)sender {

    if (!rwc)
    {
        rwc = [[ResultWindowController alloc] init];

        [rwc setValueArray:[toDoItemArrayController arrangedObjects]];
        [rwc setNumberOfCalculations:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[_inputNumberOfCalculations intValue]]];
        [rwc calculateResults]; //starts method in 2nd-window controller for result calculation

    }

    [rwc showWindow:self]; 
}
```

It might be easy but I'm afraid to always create an other ResultWindowController instance.

Thanks in advance.
Joerg

here is the ResultWindowController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ResultWindowController : NSWindowController{

    NSArray *valueArray;
    NSMutableArray *resultArray;
    NSNumber *numberOfCalculations;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSArray *valueArray;
@property (retain) NSNumber *numberOfCalculations;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSMutableArray *resultArray;

-(void)calculateResults;

@end
```

and here the ResultWindowController.m

```
#import "ResultWindowController.h"
#import "ResultItem.h" //my result model

@implementation ResultWindowController
@synthesize valueArray, resultArray, numberOfCalculations;

- (id)init
{
    if(![super initWithWindowNibName:@"ResultWindow"])
    return nil;
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{

}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];
}

- (void)calculateResults
{
    //a lot of calculation code ...

    ResultItem *newResult = [[ResultItem alloc]init];

    [newResult setValue:[nameArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"name"];
    [newResult setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:avg] forKey:@"averageValue"];
    [newResult setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:min] forKey:@"minValue"];
    [newResult setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:max] forKey:@"maxValue"];
    [newResult setValue:dimensionRandomArray forKey:@"randomArray"];

    [resultArray addObject:newResult]; 

}
```

`resultarray` is the content source for an `arraycontroller` in the ResultWindowController.xib. The `arraycontroller` is bound to a table view which is supposed to show the array content. This is not updated the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you must simply do the following:

```
- (IBAction)pushRun:(id)sender {

    if (!rwc)
    {
        rwc = [[ResultWindowController alloc] init];

        [rwc setValueArray:[toDoItemArrayController arrangedObjects]];
        [rwc setNumberOfCalculations:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[_inputNumberOfCalculations intValue]]];
        [rwc calculateResults]; //starts method in 2nd-window controller for result calculation

    }
        [rwc setValueArray:[toDoItemArrayController arrangedObjects]];
        [rwc setNumberOfCalculations:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[_inputNumberOfCalculations intValue]]];
        [rwc calculateResults]; //starts method in 2nd-window controller for result 
    [rwc showWindow:self]; 
}
```

You were only changing values of ResultWindowController if it did not exist. You want to change values no matter what, just not start a new instance. So, as long as you don't use [[alloc]init] you're good.

Hope that helps. If you need anything else, drop a comment.

### Edit

To create a property for your tableView do the following:

In .h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ResultWindowController : NSWindowController{

    NSArray *valueArray;
    NSMutableArray *resultArray;
    NSNumber *numberOfCalculations;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSArray *valueArray;
@property (retain) NSNumber *numberOfCalculations;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSMutableArray *resultArray;
@property (assign) NSTableView *yourTableView;   //Add this code
-(void)calculateResults;

@end
```

and here the ResultWindowController.m

```
#import "ResultWindowController.h"
#import "ResultItem.h" //Your result model

@implementation ResultWindowController
@synthesize valueArray, resultArray, numberOfCalculations;
@synthesize yourTableView;  //Add this code
```

Then you should be able to call `[yourTableView reloadData]`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added the code but it doesn't work. The content won't update. Do I need to send something else to push the update?

Comment: By the way the calc method `calculateResults` starts now but the results view (`tableview`) is still not updating.

Comment: Could you show your code for the other window's methods: setValueArray, setNumberOfCalculations, calculateResults.

Comment: Another thing that might contribute is that you are sending these messages to the wrong instance. However, I would think that if the window is still open, the instance would be the same. Could you verify that you are sending these to the same instance?

Comment: Thanks for keeping up. I'm pretty sure that the same instance is called because the `resultArray` values in `ResultWindowController` gets changed when user input is changed in Window-1. But the tabele view is not updating.

Comment: I'm not sure this works on Cocoa, but it does on touch. You may be need to reload data on the table view. [tableView reloadData] I believe.

Comment: You don't have a property for your tableView? How are you updating it's contents at all?

Comment: via binding to the `arraycontroller` which content is the `resultarray`.

Comment: Well, I believe the way to solve this is to create a property attached to your tableView. Then use `[tableView reloadData]` The reason it updates the first time is because you are initializing the view for the first time. After that you must call a reload of data in order for the content of the view to refresh it's data source. (In this case your array)

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it. How do I have to create a property and attach it to my table view? Sorry I'm a greenhorn.

Comment: Thanks Josiah for you help. It still does not work. I think it needs more observer code for the change in the array but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: That's odd. I have a Cocoa Touch app, that has a tableView connected it's own store (Which stores data in an array), and all I need to do is reloadData. This is an interesting situation. I'll keep looking. In the meantime, good luck!